# Wordpress main menu first item highlighted by default

Tags: css, wordpress

i have this site in wordpress, which has a menu

[image]

and the css property which changes the color on hover

```
.main-navigation a:hover {
  background: #fa5742;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

i want Home to be highlighted by default, how can i do that?
i am new to wordpress,therefor i might be missing the simplest of tricks here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proper way to do it is by highlighting the current menu item

```
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a {
  background: #fa5742;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Write Css (use First Child)

```
    .main-navigation li:first-chile a {
  background: #fa5742;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: you could elaborate what is happening

Comment: please write above code in your style.css Please use first-child

Comment: It will set the first home color but not remove on hover. And you have typo. `first-child` not `first-chile`.

Comment: @FaizanShah I am working to find solution for that. May be found before anu one

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a standard WordPress menu you could use the `.current_page_item` class to highlight the page the user is currently on.

```
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a {
  background: #fa5742;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

If like you describe you simply wish for the first item to always be highlighted you can use the following CSS.

```
.main-navigation li:first-child a {
  background: #fa5742;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```